# What book(s) cover supplemental strength and conditioning for an amateur sportsman?

Tags: workout-routines, books

I've read Starting Strength, Practical Programming, various Dan John and Pavel Tsatsouline titles, and Tom Kurz' Science of Sports Training. With the exception of that last title, all the strength and conditioning books I find are oriented towards someone with that as their primary focus. The target audience seems to be off-season sports players or amateurs just looking to lift and run. In contrast, I'm looking for material on how to integrate sports training with lifting and other supplemental work. This is difficult because most programs are designed for someone to devote themselves to it full-time, to the exclusion of other activities.

What is the best book or blog that addresses how to develop a strength and conditioning program *specifically* for someone simultaneously engaged in sports several times a week?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Athletic-Development-Science-Functional-Conditioning/dp/0736051007    http://www.amazon.com/Essentials-Strength-Training-Conditioning-Edition/dp/0736058036

Answer (score 2):

While I linked a couple of books for you in the comments, I think the best approach is going to be looking along the NSCA (National Strength and Conditioning Association) type of path, as they look at weight training not only as a stand alone activity, but as a key component of many different athletic training programs.

You will need to have an understanding of the sport that you want to apply it to, and know how to break down the motions of each sport, and understand what types of weight room activity will support those motions.

So unless you have a specific sport in mind and can look for a weight training book directed at that sport, you are probably going to want to look at books for either certification (NSCA, CSCS {Certified Strength/Conditioning Specialist}), or at kinesiology oriented textbooks (Which would also give you a lot of the physiology behind the exercises as well, which is never a bad thing).

Answer (score 0):

Elliot Hulse. Read and listen to what this man has to say. He has a youtube channel and some books for your benefit.

http://www.hulsestrength.com/

He talks about everything from intermittent fasting to central nervous system conditioning and thoracic extension. Very knowledgable. Very helpful.